# Sending and receiving message using Java Smack API not working on example

Tags: java, eclipse, xmpp, smack

I am still trying to learn how to properly work with the java Smack API, so I followed a mini-tutorial in a java programming forum here:

- [How to Write a simple XMPP (Jabber) client using the Smack API](http://www.javaprogrammingforums.com/java-networking-tutorials/551-how-write-simple-xmpp-jabber-client-using-smack-api.html)

I then changed the code to my needs. The code is posted below:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

import org.jivesoftware.smack.Chat;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.MessageListener;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.Roster;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.RosterEntry;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Message;

public class JabberSmackAPI implements MessageListener{

    private XMPPConnection connection;

    public void login(String userName, String password) throws XMPPException
    {
        ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration("localhost", 5222);
        connection = new XMPPConnection(config);

        connection.connect();
        connection.login(userName, password);
    }

    public void sendMessage(String message, String to) throws XMPPException
    {
        Chat chat = connection.getChatManager().createChat(to, this);
        chat.sendMessage(message);
    }

    public void displayBuddyList()
    {
        Roster roster = connection.getRoster();
        Collection<RosterEntry> entries = roster.getEntries();

        System.out.println("\n\n" + entries.size() + " buddy(ies):");
        for(RosterEntry r:entries)
        {
            System.out.println(r.getUser());
        }
    }

    public void disconnect()
    {
        connection.disconnect();
    }

    public void processMessage(Chat chat, Message message)
    {
        System.out.println("Received something: " + message.getBody());
        if(message.getType() == Message.Type.chat)
            System.out.println(chat.getParticipant() + " says: " + message.getBody());
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws XMPPException, IOException
    {
        // declare variables
        JabberSmackAPI c = new JabberSmackAPI();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String msg;


        // turn on the enhanced debugger
        XMPPConnection.DEBUG_ENABLED = true;


        // Enter your login information here
        System.out.println("-----");
        System.out.println("Login information:");

        System.out.print("username: ");
        String login_username = br.readLine();

        System.out.print("password: ");
        String login_pass = br.readLine();

        c.login(login_username, login_pass);

        c.displayBuddyList();

        System.out.println("-----");

        System.out.println("Who do you want to talk to? - Type contacts full email address:");
        String talkTo = br.readLine();

        System.out.println("-----");
        System.out.println("All messages will be sent to " + talkTo);
        System.out.println("Enter your message in the console:");
        System.out.println("-----\n");

        while( !(msg=br.readLine()).equals("bye"))
        {
            c.sendMessage(msg, talkTo);
        }

        c.disconnect();
        System.exit(0);
    }

}
```

In order to run this code, I have the following setup:

1. An Openfire server running, with two users: admin and user1.
2. I enabled all the ports Openfire should require to work as well
3. Eclipse IDE, when the code sample.

To run this sample, I run it using Eclipse IDE. I run this application 2 times. First I login with the admin user, and I say I want to contact with user1@openfire.com. Then I run the sample again, as user1, and I say I want to contact with admin@openfire.com.

I have the two samples running at the same time. I can write messages, but the console in the other end never seems to be receiving anything. What am I doing wrong?

I have also checked other similar posts:

- [send and receiving message using smack API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18417216/send-and-receiving-message-using-smack-api)
- [Unable to display received messages with SMACK api in JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13858092/unable-to-display-received-messages-with-smack-api-in-java)

However, they are also for specific cases and do not seem to help me, as I would like to have this sample running properly. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: according to your example, don't use "localhost" as the host

Comment: check working code http://stackoverflow.com/a/21205169/2380114

Comment: Were you able to finally resolve this issue?

Comment: I have applied that same code with smack 4.1.1 but give me so much errors.... anybody can help with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Flame_Phoenix your sample code is working, I checked with my ejabberd server. I modified the code

Make sure that you added these libraries

- **httpclient-4.1.3.jar**
- **httpcore-4.1.4.jar**
- **jstun.jar**
- **xpp3-1.1.4c.jar**

versions might be changed

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

import org.jivesoftware.smack.Chat;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.MessageListener;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.Roster;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.RosterEntry;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Message;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.util.StringUtils;

public class JabberSmackAPI implements MessageListener {

private XMPPConnection connection;
private final String mHost = "yourserver.com"; // server IP address or the
                                                // host

public void login(String userName, String password) throws XMPPException {
    String service = StringUtils.parseServer(userName);
    String user_name = StringUtils.parseName(userName);

    ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration(mHost,
            5222, service);

    config.setSendPresence(true);
    config.setDebuggerEnabled(false);

    connection = new XMPPConnection(config);
    connection.connect();
    connection.login(user_name, password);
}

public void sendMessage(String message, String to) throws XMPPException {
    Chat chat = connection.getChatManager().createChat(to, this);
    chat.sendMessage(message);
}

public void displayBuddyList() {
    Roster roster = connection.getRoster();
    Collection<RosterEntry> entries = roster.getEntries();

    System.out.println("\n\n" + entries.size() + " buddy(ies):");
    for (RosterEntry r : entries) {
        System.out.println(r.getUser());
    }
}

public void disconnect() {
    connection.disconnect();
}

public void processMessage(Chat chat, Message message) {
    System.out.println("Received something: " + message.getBody());
    if (message.getType() == Message.Type.chat)
        System.out.println(chat.getParticipant() + " says: "
                + message.getBody());
}

public static void main(String args[]) throws XMPPException, IOException {
    // declare variables
    JabberSmackAPI c = new JabberSmackAPI();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String msg;

    // turn on the enhanced debugger
    XMPPConnection.DEBUG_ENABLED = true;

    // Enter your login information here
    System.out.println("-----");
    System.out.println("Login information:");

    System.out.print("username: ");
    String login_username = br.readLine();

    System.out.print("password: ");
    String login_pass = br.readLine();

    c.login(login_username, login_pass);

    c.displayBuddyList();

    System.out.println("-----");

    System.out
            .println("Who do you want to talk to? - Type contacts full email address:");
    String talkTo = br.readLine();

    System.out.println("-----");
    System.out.println("All messages will be sent to " + talkTo);
    System.out.println("Enter your message in the console:");
    System.out.println("-----\n");

    while (!(msg = br.readLine()).equals("bye")) {
        c.sendMessage(msg, talkTo);
    }

    c.disconnect();
    System.exit(0);
}

}
```

Comment: I have the following jars: smack.jar, smackx.jar, smackx-debug.jar, smackx-jingle.jar. Are they not supposed to contain the ones you mention?

Comment: might be those inside the smack.jar, did you get any errors ?

Comment: You don't need to include any extra jars.  The first two mentioned aren't needed, as the connection is not http based, and the other two are rolled into the smack jars already.

Answer (score 2):

I tried the example with only smack and smackx added in my dependency of pom and it is working fine.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.igniterealtime.smack</groupId>
    <artifactId>smack</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.igniterealtime.smack</groupId>
    <artifactId>smackx</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

For this you will need to add one repository too

```
<repository>
    <id>nexus.opencastProject.org</id>
    <url>http://repository.opencastproject.org/nexus/content/repositories/public</url>
    <name>Opencast Nexus All Public Project Repository</name>
</repository>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

For Smack 4.1, the MessageListener interface became ChatMessageListener.  MessageListener still exists, but it has a different interface contract (processMessage takes only a Message, not a Chat).